# Design layout with scaling views

Tags: android, layout, scale

I have to design a layout as given below -

[image]

As shown in the figure - layout has two views (Relative layouts).
On Swiping on one of the views the views should scale .

What i have tried is -

1. Created  a layout with two relative layouts.
2. Handled swipe gesture on both the layouts.
3. Created animation files for scale up and scale down as given below.(sample)
4. On Swipe - animate and scale the view.

   ```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:fillEnabled="true" >

   <scale
       android:duration="2000"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="100%"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="2.0" />

   </set>
   ```

This works . 
I want to know if there is any better way to do it? 
Any resusable / built in componets for this?